# add_host - divide by os

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I want to create playbook that going on the entire inventory file and divide the servers to 2 groups: Windows and Linux (add-host going only on the first server on the inv)

I tried this code:

```
   - name: Linux Group
     add_host:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       group: LinuxGroup
     when:  hostvars[" {{ item }} "]['ansible_system']  == 'Linux'
     with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }} "
```

- This code suppose to create the linux group
  and I tried with other conditions of when but non was a succsess. I would like to get your help please.

PS:

I changed the code to this:

```
    tasks:
   - name: Create linux group
     add_host:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       group: LinuxGroup
     when: hostvars[item].ansible_system == 'Linux'
     with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }} "
     ignore_errors: yes

   - name: ping to Linux
     ping:
     with_items: LinuxGroup
```

and when I run the code the windows servers are skipped in the "Create linux group" task, but I used the module debug to print to group's items and there are the windows servers.

Answer (score 1):

The fact `ansible_system` is a key under the host, not a list of keys. Also, conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as `{{ }}` or `{% %}`, use `hostvars[item]` instead of `hostvars[ "{{ item }}" ]`.

Make sure `gather_facts` is set to `true`.

Note that the `add_host` module does not update the inventory file but updates the in-memory inventory. I have included a `debug` task to print the groups from the in-memory inventory of ansible.

```
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Linux Group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        group: LinuxGroup
      when:  hostvars[item].ansible_system == 'Linux'
      with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ groups }}"
```

Comment: I used the way you suggest before but I am getting this message:
"The conditional check 'hostvars[item].ansible_system == 'Linux
eventhoght I checked with moudle setup and this variable should be exist

Comment: Can you please provide the complete error message and the playbook you have tried?